# There is a way to prevent from someone with a source code to change a Label in WinForm?

Tags: label

As a part of my job i develop testing tools in order to optimize the tester's work.
When i'm done developing the tool, i used to leave my signature "Developed by.." and bring the source code to the testers for start working with it.
Sometimes the testers erase my name and takes my credit.
There is any way to prevent them to change my "Developed by" signature although i brought them the source code?
(I can't give them only an exec or installation file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing the source code to your testers in plain text format, there is nothing that can stop someone from removing your "Developed By" comment. You would need some history tracking mechanism, like SharePoint at the least, or a full blown version control like TFS to maintain who did what and when. That way, even if someone erases it, one would know you worked on it. Again, that wouldnt completely stop them from erasing our your name, but that helps in tracking the changes. Hope this helps!